# Issue inserting data from textbox into sqlite table

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to enter data into an sqlite database. I am using the following code, but something I am doing is wrong and it is not working.

```
  string dbConnection = "Data Source=" + dbString + ";Version=3;";
        using (SQLiteConnection myConnection = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection))
        {
            SQLiteCommand sqlCommand = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO Products (First_Name,Last_Name,Company_Name,Address1,Address2,City,State,Zip,Phone_Number1,Phone_Number2,Email_Address) Values (@First_Name, @Last_Name,@Company_Name, @Address1,@Address2, @City,@State, @Zip, @Phone_Number1, @Phone_Number2, @Email_Address,)", myConnection);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", FNAME_TXT.Text);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", LNAME_TXT.Text);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company_Name", CNAME_TXT.Text);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address1", ADDRESS1_TXT.Text);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address2", ADDRESS2_TXT.Text);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", CITY_TXT.Text);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", STATE_TXT.Text);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", ZIP_TXT.Text);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone_Number1", PHONE1_TXT.Text);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone_Number2", PHONE2_TXT.Text);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email_Address", EMAIL_TXT.Text);

            myConnection.Open();
            return sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

when I execute the code, I get:

"A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll

Additional information: SQL logic error or missing database

near ")": syntax error"

This is the code that creates the Database:

```
      sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection(dbLoc);
                sqlite_conn.Open();
                sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();
                sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Customer ("
                        + "Customer_ID_PK integer primary key,"
                        + "First_Name VARCHAR(32),"
                        + "Last_Name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,"
                        + "Company_Name VARCHAR(50),"
                        + "Address1 VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,"
                        + "Address2 VARCHAR(45),"
                        + "City VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,"
                        + "State VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,"
                        + "Zip CHAR(5) NOT NULL,"
                        + "Phone_Number1 CHAR(10) NOT NULL,"
                        + "Phone_Number2 CHAR(10),"
                        + "Email_Address VARCHAR(25))";
                sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlite_conn.Close();
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your last comma

```
... @Email_Address,)"
```

To

```
 @Email_Address)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra comma in your query.

Change this:

```
INSERT INTO Products (First_Name,Last_Name,Company_Name,Address1,Address2,City,State,Zip,Phone_Number1,Phone_Number2,Email_Address) Values (@First_Name, @Last_Name,@Company_Name, @Address1,@Address2, @City,@State, @Zip, @Phone_Number1, @Phone_Number2, @Email_Address,)
```

to:

```
INSERT INTO Products (First_Name,Last_Name,Company_Name,Address1,Address2,City,State,Zip,Phone_Number1,Phone_Number2,Email_Address) Values (@First_Name, @Last_Name,@Company_Name, @Address1,@Address2, @City,@State, @Zip, @Phone_Number1, @Phone_Number2, @Email_Address)
```